# Is it possible to force JAXB to marshall illegal characters in an XML tag?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got a database full of objects, along with user-defined properties. For example:

```
class Media {
  String name;
  String duration;
  Map<String,String> custom_tags;
}


Media:
  Name: day_at_the_beach.mp4
  Length: 4:22
  Custom Tags:
    Videographer: Charles
    Owner ID #: 17a
```

Our users can come up with their own custom properties to attach to media, and fill in values accordingly. However, when I try to marshall the object into XML, I run into problems:

```
<media>
  <name>day_at_the_beach.mp4</name>
  <length>4:22</length>
  <custom_tags>
    <Videographer>Charles</videographer>
    <Owner_ID_#>17a</Owner_ID_#>
  </custom_tags>
</media>
```

`Owner_ID_#` is an illegal tag name in XML, because it contains a `#` so JAXB throws an `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.`

I know that the preferred, *correct* way to solve this problem would be to reformat the xml to something along the lines of:

```
<custom_tags>
  <custom_tag>
    <name>Owner ID #</name>
    <value>17z</value>
  </custom_tag>
</custom_tags>
```

However, I'm *required* to return the former, invalid XML, to maintain legacy behavior from a previous, less-picky implementation of the code. Is there any way to tell JAXB not to worry about the illegal XML character, or am I going to be stuck doing a string replace before/after encoding? My current implementation is simply:

```
public static <T> String toXml(Object o, Class<T> z) {
    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(z);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(o, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a XmlAdapter for this specific object, then:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.newDocument();
document.setStrictErrorChecking(false); // <--- This one. This accomplished it.
```